# Does the a wms layer in openlayers have "maxfeatures" option?

Tags: wms, openlayers-2

Does the a wms layer in openlayers have "maxfeatures" option?

I'm asking this because my wms layer contains allot of points ( > 100.000). When zoomed in I don't want the rest of the features (not sure if you call it features when using wms) to be rendered.

When I was using WFS, this was my code:

```
    wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({
                        resFactor: 1,
                        ratio:1
                    })],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        maxFeatures:1000,
                        url:  "my url",
                        featureType: "my_featuretype",
                        featureNS: "my_feature ns",
                        version: "1.1.0"
                    })
});
```

How can I accomplish the same render functionality with a wms layer?

**Edit**

Solution: Hide the layer at a certain zoomlevel. This prevents a big amount of features to be loaded.

code:

```
    map.events.on({ "zoomend": function (e) {
        if (this.getZoom() > 7) {
            layer.setVisibility(true);
        }
        else {
            layer.setVisibility(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If taking the approach of hiding the layer then you can use the numZoomLevels or minScale/maxScale layer properties http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.numZoomLevels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A WMS uses images generated on the server so any filtering also has to be done on the server. The WMS specification does not include a MAXFEATURES parameter, but many map servers do allow filtering.

Your tag implies you are using GeoServer so have a look at its [WMS MaxFeatures](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#maxfeatures-and-startindex) option.

This is a vendor specific parameter, which can be added to your OpenLayers WMS configuration.

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Test",
                                   "http://myurl...",
                                   {layers: "test", maxfeatures: 500});
```

Comment: Thanks again haha. You've been a great help so far. I noticed that it only does render the features inside the view port, which is good! I set the visibility to false when a certain zoom level is reached. This worked, but I'll ad the maxfeatures to the layer aswel to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

in openlayers Cluster Strategy maybe solve your problem for big dataset..See [OpenLayers Cluster Strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster-js.html) .. in this method you dont need to limit yourself...

and the same handling big dataset problem in google you can read [this...](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/)

Answer (score 0):

In the arcgis for javascript,

```
lyr.setCustomParameters({
    maxFeatures:5000,
    CQL_FILTER:filter
 });
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please add a little more detail to your answer so that other people can follow your solution too?